# Custom Curve-Fitting equation doesn' t works

Tags: matlab

I am trying to fit a custom equation cumsu=a+b*(1586-x).^m to estimate the parameters a,b,m.

Data:
cumsu=[...];%The reason for which i don't give the vector cumsu is the large number of values that included.
x=[1:1586];

I would be thankful if someone can helps me.
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create custom fitting models via `fit` [function](http://www.mathworks.com/help/curvefit/fit.html).

```
fitobject = fit(x,y,fitType,fitOptions)
```

In your case you should replace `fitType` with your fitting equation:

```
CustomFit=fit(x,cumsu,'a+b*(1568-x)^m')
```

With random numbers my output was:

```
General model:
     f(x) = a+b*(1568-x)^m
     Coefficients (with 95% confidence bounds):
       a =      -2.011  (-2.959e+06, 2.959e+06)
       b =       1.479  (-2.424e+06, 2.424e+06)
       m =      0.1049  (-9.702e+04, 9.702e+04)
```